# How to write a regex to validates a middle initial in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Hoe to write a regex that validates middle initial in PHP. Because some people have more than one middle initial the regex should allow between one and and thee middle initials.
The regex should allow one letter with or wothout a period, two or three letters each followed by a period, or two or three letters each followed by a period and a single space.

Here is the list of allowed stings where 'A' means any letter of upper or lower case, including unicode letters in foreign alphabets:

```
'A', 'A.', 'A.A.', 'A. A.', 'A.A.A.', 'A. A. A.'
```

Here is a regex that I wrote as a starting point to validate exactly one midlle initial in English alpabet followed by an optional period.

```
$pattern = "/^([a-zA-Z]{1}[\.]{0,1})?$/";    
preg_match_all($pattern, $input_string, $match) > 0;
```

Comment: `$pattern = '/^(?:[A-Za-zА-Яа-яΑ-Ωα-ω](?:\.\s?|$)){1,3}$/u';
`

Comment: @Mpmp I'm getting warning  when I run your regex on PHP 7.4 "range out of order in character class"

Comment: sorry, try this `'/(?:[A-Za-zА-Яа-яΑ-Ωα-ω]\.\s?|[A-Za-zА-Яа-яΑ-Ωα-ω]{2,3}\.\s?|\s[A-Za-zА-Яа-яΑ-Ωα-ω]\s)/u'`

Comment: Is `A. A. A` a valid middle initial?

Comment: @nice_dev I would say that  A. A. A is not a valid initial because I think that people don't write their initials like that, except by mistake. But if you have an evidence to contraty, please let me know.

Comment: @Jimski Ok, can you check this? https://3v4l.org/ldoo2

Comment: @Jimski try `"/^([a-zA-Z]\.? ?){1,3}$/u"` or `"/^(\p{L}\.? ?){1,3}$/u"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so we will have 2 kinds of matches across the entire string.

- `A. A. A.` pattern where every character is followed by a `.`.
- `A A A` pattern where every character is followed by spaces and not period characters.

> As confirmed by you, `A. A A.` is NOT a valid pattern according to
> your requirement. So, we will not focus on it.

As far as regex is concerned, it will be as below,

- `\p{L}\.\s*` to match `A. A. A.` pattern. The `\p{L}` is used to match a single Unicode codepoint.
- `\p{L}\s*` to match `A A A` pattern.

Overall, the regex will be `/^((\p{L}\.\s*)+|(\p{L}\s*)+)$/iu`. The `|` is used to indicate an alternative match. So, it could be either the first capturing group or the 2<sup>nd</sup> one. The `u` flag used to treat subject strings and patterns as UTF-8. ([`see more info`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#:%7E:text=modifier%20as%20well.-,u%20(PCRE_UTF8),-This%20modifier%20turns))

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$tests = [
    'A',
    'A.',
    'A.A.',
    'A. A.',
    'A. A. A.',
    'A. A',
    'A. A A.',
    'A A. A.',
    'Ω.',
    'A.Ω.',
    'Ω',
    'A Ω.',
];

foreach($tests as $test){
    echo $test," => ", var_dump(preg_match('/^((\p{L}\.\s*)+|(\p{L}\s*)+)$/ui', $test) === 1), PHP_EOL;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](https://3v4l.org/MddRK)

---

For matching the length of only `1` or `2` or `3` initials, we can change the `+` quantifier to `{1,3}` to match the no. of initials in the range 1 - 3.

```
/^((\p{L}\.\s*){1,3}|(\p{L}\s*){1,3})$/ui
```

[**Live Demo**](https://3v4l.org/T7a6q)

Comment: @nice-dev Yes, this answer did the job beautifully and also added an extra option of validating "A A A" which although not originally specified may be useful, and if not needed it can be easily removed from the regex.

Comment: @Jimski Glad it worked. Updated my answer to suit your match length of 1-3.